# How to refactor my code to avoid raising events from outside the classes?

Tags: c#, events, refactoring

I am developing a game which contains some managers for different tasks such as collision detection, etc. Once a collision is detected, each gameobject affected by this collision should raise the `OnCollided` event, so I can easily play sounds, make the object disappear, open a door or whatever, but I cannot get this behavior without raising the event from the `CollisionSystem`, instead of letting each `GameObject` raise their own event.

Here is a simplified example, hope it makes sense:

```
Class CollisionSystem
{
    // It is called when a collision has been detected between two objects (code not included)
    public void HandleCollision(GameObject gameObject1, GameObject gameObject2)
    {
        //Do whatever
        //How can trigger each corresponding game object event from here?
    }
}

Class GameObject
{
    protected event GameEventHandler Collided;

    protected void OnCollided(GameEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Collided != null)
            Collided(this, e);
    }
}
```

I’ve tested things like making the `OnCollided` method public, but the event should be raised from inside the class... And, on the other hand, the game object itself cannot determine when it collides, cause, well, this is what the `CollisionSystem` does.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Fix code formatting please, it upsets my OCD, a smart strapping game dev jedi should have no problems

Comment: As far as I can tell from what I see here, you're doing it the wrong way around. The `OnCollided` should not be raising the event, but listening to the `OnCollided` event raised by the CollisionSystem. However, you'll want to be able to raise it to **just** the objects that are in collision, not all object subscribed to the event.

Comment: Call a public method in `GameObject` from `CollisionSistem` (should really be "system" with a y unless it's not English) which then raises the event?

Comment: Sorry, I am blind and it's really hard to me to format code here, TheGeneral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright this is what I could come up with that should embody what you're trying to do:

```
public class CollisionSystem
{
    Public void HandleCollision(IGameObject[] objects)
    {
        foreach (IGameObject obj in objects)
        {
            //call the function that tells the object it collided
            obj.CollisionDetected()
        }
    }
}
```

You'll want your gameobjects to implement an interface

```
public interface IGameObject
{
    public void CollisionDetected()
}
```

Which means your gameobject-class looks like this;

```
public class GameObject : IGameObject
{
    //constructors, params, whatever
    public void CollisionDetected()
    {
        //play some sound, remove object, whatever
    }
}
```

The thing is; I don't know what raises your collision-event.

**Edit:** so I reread your question and saw you mentioned it's begin called from the physics engine. Wherever/however that may be, if you have your `CollisionSystem` declared inside the physics-engine class, you can call the `HandleCollision()`-method from there and you'd be full circle.

Comment: In fact, by physics system, I mean collisionSystem. The HandleCollision() method is called when a collision is detected, so the parameters are just the objects that have collided. I'm testing but I think your answer works much better!

Comment: @D646 if the `CollisionSystem`-class is detecting the collisions, you can simply call the `HandleCollision()`-method and give it an array of (in my example) `IGameObjects` (or whatever else you may be using that can collide) instead of having to raise an event from the outside, makes it even easier.

Comment: So, I simply remove the event from gameobject class, and implement a public method like gameObject.hasCollided()¿

Comment: @D646 yes. Mind you, the `HasCollided()`-method you described should be in the `GameObject`-class. I'm assuming however, a door may not be a `GameObject` but for example a `TerrainObject`. That's why I proposed an interface. That way you can put all objects part of the collision in the same array when you hand them to the `HandleCollision()`-method as I showed in my answer.